# Simultaneous use of Outlook 2016 and Windows Mail for accessing an Exchange Active Sync (OX) email account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, activesync

I have an Exchange Active Sync (OX) email account, so it's not an official MS Exchange email account.  I currently have it set up to work with Outlook 2016, but the problem is that Outlook can't sync Calendars via Active Sync.  My understanding is that the built-in Windows Mail/Calendar Client (Win 10) does Sync the Calendar.  My thought was to use Windows Mail for calendar, appointment requests, etc. but continue to to Outlook for emails.  When I try to set up this same email account on the same computer, Windows Mail says that the account already exists so it won't allow me to complete the setup. Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest fixing the Exchange to fully sync. Windows Mail will not sync if Outlook cannot sync.

Comment: It's a 3rd part OX Email account, which is Exchange compatible but only sync the Calendar events through ActiveSync (EAS)

Comment: Ask the Vendor Support.  Our Clients all use 3rd party Hosted Exchange and calendars (and contacts) with Outlook sync properly at all times.

Comment: Yeah, I tried (Namecheap).  They said the OX (Open-Xchange) no longer supports Outlook for Calendar syncing with.  Their suggestion was to use WIndows Mail client.  May have to change vendors at this point

Comment: As John mentioned above, I'm afraid that this might be related to your email account it self, please try to follow the suggestions they provide and see if the issue has any difference.